# multiple entities that share a table

Tags: erd

I have this situation where i have two different entities, `Researcher` and `Lab Manager` and i want for a both to have a profile.

When a user logs in he could be one of the two entities, and searching in both tables for a username can be inefficient, so i think both of theme sharing a table called profile would be the way to go.

here is my attempt

[image: ER Diagram]

but i realized two issues with it

- instead of a researcher or manager have a profile, a profile have to have both a researcher and a manager as owners in the same time
- when i query for a user how can i know his type without adding an attribute of type

any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Allow `Field` to be NULL and every user that has no `Field` is researcher.

If field isn't enough there is also TeamId which can be -1 for magaers.

Or a combination of both

But to be honest a Type field make a lot if sense as Tinyint, and you  are felible for future as there must be student helpers and so on

Comment: but the entities needs to stay the way they are because the researcher is going to be a part of a team, while the manager is going to manage a lab.

Comment: I took what you gave as information and gave you my opinion . With new circumstances ancrs it is normal to adept the database  or you add new logic like I did

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to talk to the specific issues with your modelling without knowing the entire background or universe of discourse.

> instead of a researcher or manager have a profile, a profile have to have both a researcher and a manager as owners in the same time

You can mark the relations as 0..1 (zero to one) rather than 1..1 (one to one). Refer to this [link](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning) and the ER diagram notation section for how to show cardinality and ordinality.

> when i query for a user how can i know his type without adding an attribute of type

By Joining the table profile to each respective role table, or checking if the Profile ID exists in the Manager or Researcher table. It is up to your design and needs to determine if it's best to have a type attribute on the profile.